# Use middlewares conditionally - Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to make a POST request where I need to switch between two middlewares based on a `req.body` parameter. The two middlewares are `auth` middlewares for `customer` and `merchant` respectively. I send a `type` in request body and its value can be either customer or merchant.

The merchantAuth and customerAuth middlewares are almost alike so I'm only writing one here.
So far I have done this:

**router.js:**

```
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (req.body.type == 'customer') {
      customerAuth(req, res, next);
    }
    else if (req.body.type == 'merchant') {
      merchantAuth(req, res, next);
    }
    return res.json('done');
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send('Internal server error. ' + err.message);
  }
});
```

**merchantAuth/customerAuth:**

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  // Get token from header
  const token = req.header('x-auth-token');
  // Check if no token
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json("Authorization denied");
  }
  // Verify token
  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.jwtAccessSecret);
    if (!decoded.customer) {
      return res.status(401).json("Invalid token");
    }
    req.customer = decoded.customer;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(401).json("Invalid token");
  }
};
```

The error I get is
*Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
(node:11152) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11).....
....*

I know why I'm getting this error but I don't know why I'm getting it and how to solve it. If I provide a wrong auth token for a customer, it gives an error on `if (!decoded.customer)` condition and then returns. However, it continues to execute on the router.js file until `return res.json('done');` line where it gives me this error.
Why does the execution on router.js continue when I have already given response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code executes `res.json('done')` after calling the authentication middleware so that *two* responses are sent in case of failed authentication, leading to the observed error. You want to execute `res.json('done')` only when the authentication middleware calls `next()`:

```js
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  function nextAfterAuthentication() {
    res.json('done');
  }
  try {
    if (req.body.type == 'customer') {
      customerAuth(req, res, nextAfterAuthentication);
    }
    else if (req.body.type == 'merchant') {
      merchantAuth(req, res, nextAfterAuthentication);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send('Internal server error. ' + err.message);
  }
});
```

Or, equivalently

```js
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (req.body.type == 'customer') {
      customerAuth(req, res, next);
    }
    else if (req.body.type == 'merchant') {
      merchantAuth(req, res, next);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send('Internal server error. ' + err.message);
  }
}, function() {
  res.json('done');
});
```

Comment: But shouldnt the return res.status(401).json("Invalid token"); statement in the middleware stop the execution?

Comment: No, the `return` statement only returns from the authentication middleware, after which the `return res.json('done');` command is executed.